# Debugging invalid utf-8 characters in python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, utf-8

I am trying to debug why certain strings in my python3 script have non-utf8 characters. I found this script that should identify such characters:

https://rgxdb.com/r/5A2OX1FG

The web site gives python code for it:

```
regex = r"""
    (?:
        [\xC0-\xC1] # Invalid UTF-8 Bytes
      | [\xF5-\xFF] # Invalid UTF-8 Bytes
      | \xE0[\x80-\x9F] # Overlong encoding of prior code point
      | \xF0[\x80-\x8F] # Overlong encoding of prior code point
      | [\xC2-\xDF](?![\x80-\xBF]) # Invalid UTF-8 Sequence Start
      | [\xE0-\xEF](?![\x80-\xBF]{2}) # Invalid UTF-8 Sequence Start
      | [\xF0-\xF4](?![\x80-\xBF]{3}) # Invalid UTF-8 Sequence Start
      | (?<=[\x0-\x7F\xF5-\xFF])[\x80-\xBF] # Invalid UTF-8 Sequence Middle
      | (?<![\xC2-\xDF]|[\xE0-\xEF]|[\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]|[\xF0-\xF4]|[\xF0-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]|[\xF0-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]{2})[\x80-\xBF] # Overlong Sequence
      | (?<=[\xE0-\xEF])[\x80-\xBF](?![\x80-\xBF]) # Short 3 byte sequence
      | (?<=[\xF0-\xF4])[\x80-\xBF](?![\x80-\xBF]{2}) # Short 4 byte sequence
      | (?<=[\xF0-\xF4][\x80-\xBF])[\x80-\xBF](?![\x80-\xBF]) # Short 4 byte sequence (2)
    )
    """  

def stripNonUtf8(str):
    matches = re.search(regex, str, re.VERBOSE)
    if matches:
        print ("Match was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(start = matches.start(), end = matches.end(), match = matches.group()))
```

but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log2db.py", line 330, in <module>
    main()
  File "log2db.py", line 325, in main
    stripNonUtf8("aaa")
  File "log2db.py", line 38, in stripNonUtf8
    matches = re.search(regex, str, re.VERBOSE)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 183, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 286, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 930, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 426, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 816, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 426, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 736, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, verbose, nested + 1)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 426, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 536, in _parse
    code1 = _class_escape(source, this)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 309, in _class_escape
    raise source.error("incomplete escape %s" % escape, len(escape))
re.error: incomplete escape \x0 at position 411 (line 10, column 11)
```

what is going on?

Comment: There's no need for this. Simply attempting to read the file as text (which will implicitly set the encoding to UTF-8 if your system is configured for it; or you can explicitly `open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')`) will produce an error message for any invalid byte sequences. Similarly, `str.decode('utf-8')` will raise an exception if the `bytes` object `str` contains any invalid sequences. There are options to `decode` and alternative encodings you can use, but wrap this in some `try`/`except` and you should have all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. We are reading from different sources, including compressed files with different compression. This makes life harder (as an exception is thrown that a symbol cannot by mapped)

Comment: So catch that exception. Or try with `errors` set to something suitable. https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers

Comment: Note: you specified a string. A string is not encoded (so it is not UTF-8). You should prefix with `b` if you want a binary array (like a UTF-8 string).

Comment: @tripleee: so given a str that came through who knows where (gzip, 7zip, regular  text file, etc.) how should I (i) eliminate the non-utf8 and (ii) find non-utf8 from a string? `str = bytes(str, 'utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'replace')` still let through some non-utf8 characters (`0xf6 0x73 0x63 0x68`)

Comment: What's your actual input there?

Comment: @tripleee: the actual input is str. I am replacing it for further processing

Comment: Yes, but what does the variable `str` contain at the beginning of this processing?

Comment: @tripleee: thanks for a follow up. I open a file. This might be zip, 7zip, gzip, text file, or someone calls my function with a parameter. The encoding of the string is very hard to guess.

Comment: If you can show me something like `str = bytes([0x91, 0x92, 0x93])` I can try to repro the comment I am trying to respond to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike in C, in Python it is required for a character with a hex value to be specified with exactly 2 digits.

Please refer to the documentation of [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), where it is noted:

> Unlike in Standard C, exactly two hex digits are required.

So the code should be fixed with:

```
| (?<=[\x00-\x7F\xF5-\xFF])[\x80-\xBF] # Invalid UTF-8 Sequence Middle
```

In addition, the capabilities of Python's standard `re` module are relatively limited. You can install the regex module (`pip install regex`) and do `import regex as re` to work around the limitations.

Comment: Indeed! It also seems to `python3` that there's something wrong with this string as well: `| (?<![\xC2-\xDF]|[\xE0-\xEF]|[\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]|[\xF0-\xF4]|[\xF0-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]|[\xF0-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]{2})[\x80-\xBF] # Overlong Sequence`

Comment: makes sense to add this info as part of the answer :-) maybe even mentioning, that the `Overlong Sequence` line as well

Comment: `regex` is way more capable than the standard `re` library but I would not call the standard library "quite limited" either.

Comment: @tripleee Agreed. Revised my wording as suggested.